# JPA @OneToMany persists, but @ManyToOne does not persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Hibernate/JPA and am having some issues understanding JPA persistance with all these annotations.  I have 2 simple Entities with a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship between the 2 and I'm not understanding how the persistance between the 2 works.

Here are my Entities and Relationships:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVICE_TABLE")
public class DeviceEntity implements Serializable {
...

@Id
private String serialNumber;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "deviceEntity")
private Set<AlertsEntity> alerts = new HashSet<AlertsEntity>(0);
...



@Entity
@Table(name = "ALERT_TABLE")
public class AlertsEntity implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "serialNumber", nullable = false)
private DeviceEntity deviceEntity;
...
```

And here's how I'm trying to use them using my DAOs inbetween:

```
String serialNumber = "asdf";

DeviceEntity device = new DeviceEntity(serialNumber, new HashSet<AlertsEntity>());
deviceService.addDeviceEntity(device);

AlertsEntity alertEntity = new AlertsEntity(device, "Alert1");
device.getAlerts().add(alertEntity);

alertService.addAlertsEntity(new AlertsEntity(device, "Alert2"));

List<AlertsJson> alertsFromDeviceService = deviceService.getJsonableAlerts(serialNumber);
List<AlertsJson> alertsFromAlertService = alertService.getJsonableAlerts(device);

assertEquals(2, alertsFromAlertService.size()); //passes
assertEquals(2, alertsFromDeviceService.size()); //FAILS!
```

Now here's the part I don't understand... I thought by settings up these 2 relationships, that the 2 Entities are linked together, so when I add/remove from one, the other one is updated.

But when I add an Alert thru the DeviceEntity, the Alert Entity gets updated, but when I add an alert thru the Alert Entity, the Device Entity does NOT get updated.  Is this correct? Am I missing something?  If that's the case, what's the point of having an Alert Entity and a relationship?

**--Update: TL;DR --**

Here's my main question: when I update an entity and set a field which is marked @ManyToOne, does that automatically persist to the other table with which it is linked to?

So in the example above, if I create a new AlertEntity and set the DeviceEntity field, will this alert be available in my Set inside the DeviceEntity when I say DeviceEntity.getAlerts()?

Comment: Show us the code that you're executing, tell us what you think it should do, and tell us what it does instead.

Comment: That second block of code is what i'm executing in a JUnit test, I expect the last line to pass, not fail. The rest of the code I didn't include is basic DAO/Service stuff for both entities which I figured would muddy up the waters, nothing interesting in there.  I guess my main question is, when I update an entity and set a field which is marked @ManyToOne, does that automatically persist to the other table with which it is linked to?